# Update link module of an existing link chain in IBM DOORS client 9.6

Tags: ibm-doors

I have mistakenly used a wrong link module between module A and B. I now changed the link module to the correct one, but the previously created links remain assigned to the previous link module. How can I change all at once to the new link module?

Answer (score 1):

if you only have a few links/modules to be corrected, follow IBMs advise at https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-move-links-between-link-modules-manually-without-using-dxl

1. insert a traceability column
2. convert layout column to DXL attribute
3. Use 'Link by attribute' to create links with the new link module
4. delete old links

Otherwise you will have to create a DXL script which iterates over the modules, objects and links and creates new links and deletes old links